# An Existing Git Repository was found

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to setting up GitHub and linking it to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. I'm not new to Git nor Visual Studio but linking them together properly is all new to me. I figure it'll be easier to explain what I'm doing using screenshots. I've already added the GitHub extension to VS and linked it to my account. I'm attempting to create a new Repository in GitHub and then add various projects to it as I develop them.

The first thing I do is open the Team Explorer, go to the GitHub section, and click Create to create a new repo.

[image]

This is the information I enter when creating a new repo. I leave most things default but I do set the repo as Private since this is just my personal code that I don't wish to share.

[image]

As you can see, at this point the repo has been created. Now the next step is to create a Solution so I can add various programs like a console application to back up my files.

[image]

To add the solution I go back to the Team Explorer, go to the Solution section, and click on "New".

[image]

Clicking "New" brings up the "New Project" window. Below is the information I entered.

[image]

After I click "OK" VS creates the solution and the project however there's a red symbol next to them indicating that they are ignored by Git.

[image]

In an attempt to remedy this, I right-click on the Solution, and click on "Add Solution to Source Control".

[image]

However, when I do that I'm given the error message shown below.

[image]

I'm very confused on what this even means. "An existing Git repository was found"...that's what I previously did. That's the whole point of using Git. Shouldn't VS simply push this solution to the repo it's currently connected to? I've honestly never seen this before but my experience is with Microsoft TFS/Azure and not GitHub. Does anyone have any ideas how to add a solution and corresponding projects to an existing GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a new repo and then a new project, try to do it inverted: first create the project and then add it to a new GitHub repository that you create.